# Gridview DataSource has rows, but GridView doesn't

Tags: c#, .net

The first time I load the GridView it's fine.  Then I sort on a column and the GridView comes back with no rows.  The debugger shows that there are rows in the DataSource table, but there are none in the GridView itself.  (Note that I'm creating the GridView dynamically, but that shouldn't matter as far as I know.)

These are the lines of code:

```
gv.DataSource = dv;    
gv.DataBind();
```

Nothing special.

These are the values the debugger shows when stepping through the code.

Before the first line:

```
dv.Table.Rows.Count 23

((System.Data.DataView)(gv.DataSource)).Table.Rows.Count    '((System.Data.DataView)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl)(gv)).DataSource))' is null

gv.Rows.Count   0
```

After the first line:

```
dv.Table.Rows.Count 23

((System.Data.DataView)(gv.DataSource)).Table.Rows.Count    23

gv.Rows.Count   0
```

After the second line of code:

```
dv.Table.Rows.Count 23

((System.Data.DataView)(gv.DataSource)).Table.Rows.Count    23

gv.Rows.Count   0
```

Comment: is this `Web Forms` or `Win Forms` if it's a web application you need to check of `if(IsPostBack){}` in the `Page_Load` also could you show the actual Events code that these are happening...? you need to show how you are implementing `dv` we can't see what you are looking at. `DataBinding` issue you are experiencing

Comment: After sorting, do you reassign the GridView's DataSource and rebind it? If not, you need to.

Comment: It's Web Forms.  This is the entire routine.
gv.Columns.Clear();

if (dv != null)
{
   AddColumnsToGrid(gv_report, dv);    
   dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + Direction;
}

if (report_id.Value == "")
   gv.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "report_id" };
else
{
   Report.report_id = Convert.ToInt32(report_id.Value);
   Report.Get();
   string[] dataKeyNames = Report.data_key_names.Split();
   gv.DataKeyNames = dataKeyNames;
}

gv.DataSource = dv;
gv.DataBind();

Comment: @Melanie, yes.  That's the two lines of code I referenced in the original post.  That's why I don't get that the row count should be different before and after the DataBind.

gv.DataSource = dv;  
gv.DataBind();

Comment: Sorry the the formatting of my code samples. This is my first post and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Back to the fact that this is a dynamically created GridView.  I can step through the code and see that the InstantiateIn method of the ITemplate class is being called for each row, so I'm certain that the rows are being added to the GridView.  Nevertheless, as soon as the last row is added, it returns back to the DataBind and states that there are no rows in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [these are the droids you're looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx).

Hint: It's the MSDN article for manually handling the `Sorting` event, which you need to do if you bind the DataSource manually.

Comment: I didn't want to get too caught up in the sorting aspect.  I can sort other grids in the application fine, so I understand that concept.  It's this one that's stumping me.  I do not understand why the Gridview DataSource has rows, but GridView doesn't.  They should be the same after binding.  At least I thought they should.

Comment: Well, what I gather from the MSDN docs is that if you bind the datasource manually then you have to provide the sorting mechanisms manually as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I am doing that just prior to these lines.  The problem is that the DataBind isn't returning any rows.

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable on this subject but I remember having to call some kind of Refresh() method for the databinding in WinForms. Maybe a similar mechanism is needed for WebForms. If lazy loading is used, maybe the rows are only loaded when needing to be shown (forceably if needed).

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: For anyone who might run across this problem, I don't know exactly why this caused the problem, but when you create GridView columns dynamically you need to re-create them on postback.  During that recreation, for this particular load I was always setting it to sort ASC (which would then secondarily hit the Sort routine and sort properly).  When returning back to sort the data, my manual setting to ASC conflicted with the default behavior to switch to DESC and for whatever reason would result in all rows being removed from the GridView on DataBind even though it's DataSource's DataView had data.  While this shouldn't have caused a problem, it did.  Once I removed the manual sort in PageLoad it worked (I didn't really, but that's getting into the weeds of my application).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also coming across this problem, mine had a different cause. **Once used a `DataView`** on a DataTable, the **databinding to the GridView control failed to show all results in the DataTable.**

I have a DataTable loaded into a session variable. I bind a GridView using that session variable `DataTable table = Session["mytable"] as DataTable`.

Once I created a `DefaultView` of the DataTable object, and performed a .DataBind() on any control, the GridView showed no results upon DataBind(), however there actually was data in the DataTable.

The **solution** was to create a copy of the DataTable into a local variable to show the DefaultView of the data in that single webcontrol (DropDownList).

**Code:**

```
DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)grvTasks.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("cmb_TaskStartsAfter"));
DataTable copytable = LoadedTasks.Copy();
DataView v = copytable.DefaultView;
v.RowFilter = "TSK_ID  " + r["TSK_ID"];
ddl.DataSource = v;
```